# Failed To Save Custom CSS Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, web

I have a wordpress website running on my local machine. I copied all files to remote server and database too. Unfortunately it is not working probably on the remote server with the following error:

> Failed To Save Custom CSS. Make Sure you have Write permission in wp-contents/plugins folder.
>   '; }else{ echo '
>   Saved Settings
>   '; } } $startCode=get_option("CBS_StartCode")=="" ? "
>   ":get_option("CBS_StartCode");
>    $endCode=get_option("CBS_EndCode")=="" ? "
>   ":get_option("CBS_EndCode"); $vchecked=get_option("CBS_InVisual")=="" ? "checked='checked'":""; $tchecked=get_option("CBS_InText")=="" ? "checked='checked'":""; $pchecked=get_option("CBS_PTag")=="" ? "checked='checked'":""; ?>

Any help!

Answer (score 1):

Add proper File Permission to your plugin Directory, see this official documentation [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions)

[image]